# How do I synchronize access to a member of a different class?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I'm trying to figure out how to synchronize read/write access to a synchronized list from a different class.

A small example: I have a synchronized list in one class `ListProvider` and I access it in a different class `Filter`. As the name suggests, this class performs some filtering based on a (in)validation check `isInvalid`.

The `filter` method first gets the list reference, then collects the entries to remove in a temporary list to not run into concurrent modification issues, and finally removes the entries from the list:

```
public class Filter {

    ListProvider listProvider;

    ...

    public void filter() {
        List<String> listProviderList = listProvider.getList();

        List<String> entriesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        // collect
        for (String entry : listProviderList)
            if (isInvalid(entry)) {
                entriesToRemove.add(entry);
            }
        }

        // remove
        for (String entry : entriesToRemove) {
            listProviderList.remove(entry);
        }       
    }
}
```

My question: How can I make sure that no other thread modifies the list while `filter` does its reading and writing?

If it were `Filter`'s own list, I'd just do:

```
synchronized(myList) {
    // collect
    // remove
}
```

but in this case I'm not sure what to use as a monitor.

Comment: **All** access to the list has to be synchronized. So if another thread gets the list, they also need to synchronize on it before using it. That might not be possible if you don't control the code. Consider wrapping the list returned with some synchronization. Check out the `Collections` class.

Comment: Return copy of the original list when calling `listProvider.getList()`

Comment: @hoaz But then I'd lose all possible updates to the list between ListProvider#getList and ListProvider#setList. Consistency/correctness of the original list is most important, I do not care much about performance. Access should simply happen on a FCFS basis.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The `Collections` class would not be of any use, here. It would only synchronize each individual access, but would not ensure that items slated for removal hadn't already been removed by another thread. The entire collect-invalid-entries-and-removed-them process has to be made atomic. Call-by-call synchronization is rarely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but in this case I'm not sure what to use as a monitor.

To create a monitor for a specific task, it is a good pattern to use a `private final Object`:

```
 private final Object listUpdateLock = new Object();
 ...
 synchronized(listUpdateLock) {
    ...
 }
```

It's important to make sure that `ListProvider` is `private` and that all accesses to the list are done within a `synchronized` block -- even if only reading from it.

In this case, you are updating the list, you could create a temporary list and then replace it when you are done.  I'm not sure you can do that with `ListProvider` however.  Then you could just make the list `volatile`.

Comment: But then all access needs to use that monitor, no? Let's say I have ten or a thousand threads performing modifications on that list - if only one would use `listUpdateLock`, the other threads would still have access to the list.

Comment: Yep.  That's the nature of threaded programming @htorque.  If one threads modifies the list, the other threads need to see that modification.  You could use something like a `ConcurrentSkipList` if you want higher performance on the updates.

Answer (score 2):

Here it seems like you should use a [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). A lock is like synchronized but it's a bit more flexible. It doesn't require a surrounding block and it has some extended features. There are also some different kinds of locks. [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) is much like synchronized.

```
public class ListProvider<E> {
    private final List<E> theList = new ArrayList<E>();
    private final ReentrantLock listLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public final List<E> lockList() {
        listLock.lock();
        return theList;
    }

    public final void unlockList() {
        listLock.unlock();
    }
}

/* somewhere else */ {

    List<E> theList = listProvider.lockList();

    /*
     * perform
     * multiple
     * operations
     *
     */

    listProvider.unlockList();
}
```

The main differences between this and synchronized are:

- The actual locking mechanism is hidden. This is good for abstraction; however,
- Clients must remember to unlock explicitly whereas a synchronized monitor exit is at a block delimiter.

There is a lock called [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) which you might find useful because multiple threads can read simultaneously. [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) explains how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Do not iterate over original list, but create a copy of it to find invalid elements. When you are done with filtering you can remove invalid elements from original list safely:

```
public class Filter {

    ListProvider listProvider;

    ...

    public void filter() {
        List<String> listProviderCopy = new ArrayList<>(listProvider.getList());

        List<String> entriesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        // collect
        for (String entry : listProviderCopy)
            if (isInvalid(entry)) {
                entriesToRemove.add(entry);
            }
        }

        listProvider.getList().removeAll(entriesToRemove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `SynchronizedList`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> synch = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

[more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: In fact, the `listProviderList` is such a construct, but that doesn't help when you need to perform multiple actions in a single synchronized block.

Comment: If you perform multiple actions in single synchronization block you can create a lock for all resoruces used in that block so until it ends nothing can change them from outside.

Comment: That will only make each individual call synchronized, but it will not make the entire process of collecting the invalid entries and then removing them atomic.